40mm f/2.8 or 50mm f/1.8 on APS-C for versatile shooting?
I'd like to get a new lens, but I'm not sure weather to choose a focal length of 40 mm or 50 mm (mounted on APS-C) : the EF 40 mm f/2.8   or the    EF 50 mm f/1.8 from Canon
I'm not specialized in portrait photography, I'd like a versatile lens that is good for portraits, but also for street and landscape photography, a small lens that is handy in vacations for instance. I know it's not 100% possible to get one lens that is perfect for everything, but as I'm not a specialist, I guess it's okay
I'm afraid the 50 mm lens on my APS-C would be too much, especially for street photography. This is why I'm considering the 40 mm lens. I mostly shoot between 40 and 55 mm on my 18-55 mm f/3.5-5.6 lens that came with my canon.
I feel limited by low light on my current lens. Do you think the f2.8 one would be sufficient ? f/2.8 compared to f/5.6 is already a huge step in term of light
I've read a lot about these two lenses but still can't figure out which is the best option for someone who isn't fully into portraits, but still likes bokeh and want to shoot in low light condition
I should precise I'm still a beginner.I've had my camera for a few years now (canon 2000d), but I don't practice much.
Thank you

Both may be longer than you want for street photography with APS-C, depending on your style, being slightly telephoto. The 'normal' range for an APS-C is between about 30mm and 20mm.

Check the EF-S 24mm f/2.8 "pancake" (quite cheap), or the Sigma 30mm f/1.4

davolfmann, i know it's quite long, but this is my focal range, according to details provided by Lightroom, I usually shoot between 40 - 55 mm with my current lens. For wider angle, I'll stay with my 18-55, as I find ok in this range
xenoid, the Canon pancake is exactly the one I'm thinking about. I just checked the Sigma 30 mm, I find it a bit too expensive for my level

Did you see this question about the same two lenses?

It's honestly a little unclear what help you're looking for from the community here - we can't really tell you whether you would prefer 40mm vs 50mm, or f/1.8 vs f/2.8 as that's incredibly personal to your own photography. At the moment I'm leaning towards closing this as a duplicate of the question Ross has linked to, but feel free to edit your question to explain what help you're looking for. Thanks!

You should just resign yourself to the fact that eventually you will want more than one new lens.  The choice for today would depend on what attribute of your current lens you find most constraining.

The thing about this choice is that there are affordable zoom lenses with a maximum aperture of 2.8 that go from 17-50 or 17-55 or similar. Those usually even come with image stabilization.
Unless you have very good reasons why you absolutely want a prime lens, such a zoom lens is probably a better choice than a 40 2.8 whose aperture and focal length would already be covered by the zoom lens. This is why between these, it makes more sense to buy the 50 1.8 which has the real advantage of actually giving you a maximum aperture that isn't covered by many zoom lenses.


I'm not specialized in portrait photography, I'd like a versatile lens that is good for portraits,

In portraits you can't beat the ability to have a suitable distance from your subject, and large aperture opening (focal length divided by f-number). The reason being that if you have let's say 35mm full frame equivalent lens, you have to step very close or have lots of environment at the sides of your subject. Maybe that's what you like, maybe you want a portrait to emphasize the relationship between the subject and its environment, without focusing too much on the subject. But for many portraits, 35mm full frame equivalent means you have to crop, and you don't have lots of background blur then, firstly because the aperture opening of let's say 35mm/1.8 is less than 50mm/1.8, secondly because to get maximum background blur, you have to have equal framing and with 35mm/1.8 you have wider framing than 50mm/1.8 from the same distance.
This brings to aperture opening. Aperture opening (focal length divided by f-number) dictates how much background blur you can have. Of course, you can choose to stop down to have less background blur. But you can't choose to stop up from the lenses maximum aperture opening.

but also for street and landscape photography

For street photography, focal lengths can vary depending on what kinds of pictures you take. For landscape photography, there is a unique problem that you can't choose to step closer or step backwards, you are dictated by the focal length. Sometimes a tele is what you want, at other times a wide angle lens is what you want. Many landscape photographers want a high resolution image so if you want a tele and have a wide angle with you, the cropping reduces the resolution.

a small lens that is handy in vacations for instance

For vacations unless you are planning to shoot wildlife as well, a reasonably wide-ish lens is useful (let's say 35mm full frame equivalent): you can always crop but you can't make a tele into a wide angle. However, if you want to shoot portraits as well during a vacation (a vacation creates a unique setting for portraits), having a portrait lens with you is useful.

I'm afraid the 50 mm lens on my APS-C would be too much, especially for street photography.

Indeed, 50mm on APS-C limits how much stuff you can put into your frame, unless you have room to step back a lot, in which case you can clearly see from the perspective that the photo is taken quite far away with a tele-ish lens.

This is why I'm considering the 40 mm lens. I mostly shoot between 40 and 55 mm on my 18-55 mm f/3.5-5.6 lens that came with my canon.

Maybe from this experiment you can deduce that 40mm f/2.8 is better for you, however, in most cases 50mm f/1.8 would be considered a better portrait lens (and it's a very cheap lens as well, a useful tool to have in any kit).

I feel limited by low light on my current lens.

A 35mm f/2 from Canon would probably be the best bet in this case, but unfortunately, it's quite expensive as a lens. It has image stabilization however, so it's even better as a low light lens than a non-stabilized 40mm f/2.8.

Do you think the f2.8 one would be sufficient ?

The aperture isn't that big, the lens from Canon it isn't image stabilized, maybe not. But maybe it is, only you can know if f/2.8 is a big enough aperture and if you can do without image stabilization. Do some test shots with as big aperture as you can with your kit zoom at 40mm, with image stabilization off, maybe you can extrapolate from that at what shutter speeds your shots are non-shaken and how f/2.8 over your current aperture helps with the shutter speed.

I've read a lot about these two lenses but still can't figure out which is the best option for someone who isn't fully into portraits, but still likes bokeh and want to shoot in low light condition

To me, if you have the money to spend, BOTH 35mm f/2 and 50mm f/1.8 is an option to consider. 35mm f/2 since it is a very versatile image stabilized low light lens and 50mm f/1.8 because it's simply so good for bokeh and portraits, and not very expensive. Think like this: 35mm f/2 could be an ideal lens for you, and 50mm f/1.8 could be just so cheap compared to it that having not only 35mm f/2 but also 50mm f/1.8 doesn't increase your costs that much.
Even if you shoot usually between 40mm-55mm, sometimes the extra field of view that 35mm gives is helpful. Also you can always choose to crop the 35mm picture into a 40mm-55mm picture, since the Canon's 35mm f/2 is a sharp-ish lens (if you get the newer image stabilized version and not the very old very cheap very low-quality (optically) version).
35mm f/2 isn't a very wide lens on a crop camera. If I planned to go on a vacation with a full frame camera, I'd likely pick a 35mm f/1.8 (RF) lens, maybe adding 85mm f/1.8 (EF) to it for portraits. But since you said most of your shooting is between 40mm-55mm, maybe 35mm would be ideal for you on a crop camera and way too wide for you on a full frame camera.
Of course, to someone on a crop camera which probably isn't that expensive, spending the money for a 35mm f/2 could be too much for your budget. But consider it at least even if you reject it.

Oh, and something important to add. At these times, when everyone is getting themselves rid of Canon EF 35mm f/2 and wanting Canon RF 35mm f/1.8 instead, you can find a lot of very good bargains for a used good quality lens for EF 35mm f/2. Just search for it! A used EF 35mm f/2 could very well be what's ideal for you.

The 50mm is a little better suited to portraiture, the 40mm is a little better suited to street and landscape photography. (Unless you're doing street photography in low light, in which case the larger aperture of the 50mm will be a great benefit.) Choose whichever thing you want to concentrate on a bit more than the other, buy a lens and get to shooting with it.
